# Vertical fading in VerticalGridView doesn't work

Tags: android, android-xml, androidx, leanback

I am trying to set up a vertical fading edge on my androidx.leanback.widget.VerticalGridView without success.

If I replace VeticalGridView with RecyclerView, everything looks ok.

Only what I am using in Fragment/Activity is to set adapter on gridView and number of columns.

```
<androidx.leanback.widget.VerticalGridView
    android:id="@+id/rv_view_all_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/custom_dim_14"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/custom_dim_150"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/custom_dim_57"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/custom_dim_56"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cl_view_all_top_view"
    tools:listitem="@layout/card_item" />
```

Thanks